# Problems with deleting punctuation in list of lists

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to write prolog code that will delete all punctuation (.,!? etc) from all lists in a list of lists. This is what I have so far:

```
delete_punctuation(_,[],_).
delete_punctuation(Character,[List|Tail],Resultlist) :- 
    delete(List,Character,NewList),
    delete_punctuation(Character,Tail,[NewList|Resultlist]).
```

whereas 'Character' will be 33 for ! or 46 for . and so on since I will be using this only on lists of character codes. (I know, that the function would actually work for other elements that I would like to delete from the lists too.)

The results I receive when asking:

```
delete_punctuation(33,[[45,33,6],[4,55,33]],X).
```

is just

```
|: true.
```

However, I want it to be:

```
|: X = [[45,6],[4,55]].
```

What do I need to improve?

Comment: Your base case looks incorrect. `delete_punctuation(_,[],_)` says that you don't care what the result of deleting punctuation from the empty list is. But I would submit that you care very much what the result is. :) And then your main clause will have some issue since you really want the `Resultlist` to be `[NewList|Rest]` where `Rest` is the result of your recursive `delete_punctuation`.

Comment: Your problem is in any case underspecified. What do you expect from `delete_punctuation(33,[[33,33]], X)`? Should both be deleted or only one? And what, of there is none?

Comment: @lurker : so my base case should be `delete_punctuation(_,[],[]).` and maybe I should add another case such as `delete_punctuation(Character,[[Character|T1]|T2],Resultlist) :- delete_punctuation(Character,[T1|T2],Resultlist)` ?

Comment: @false : I expect `delete_punctuation(33,[[33,33]],X).` to have the result `X = [[]]`

Comment: Correct on the base case change. I don't think you need to add another case, though. The logic in your current recursive clause just needs a wee bit of rework. You basically have the result handling backwards. The head of the clause should be, `delete_punctuation(Character, [List|Tail], [NewList|Resultlist])` and the recursive call should be, `delete_punctuation(Character, Tail, Resultlist)`. In other words, it's the result of this clause that should be growing by the inclusion of `NewList`.

Comment: Does @lurker's change actually fail for `delete_punctuation(33,[[33,33]],[[33]])`?

Comment: Like I commented above, I would like to delete both of the 33 in that case, which is why it does not actually fail. Thank you for your help though! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, I'd tackle it by addressing the two sub-problems separately, namely:

- Filter/exclude a character code from a single list;
- Applying the solution to the above to a list of lists of character codes.

To this end, I'd approach it like this:

```
exclude2(_, [], []).
exclude2(Code, [Code|Xs], Ys) :-
  !, % ignore the next clause if codes match
  exclude2(Code, Xs, Ys).
exclude2(Code, [X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
  % else, Code != X here
  exclude2(Code, Xs, Ys).
```

Note that some implementations like [SWI-Prolog provide `exclude/3` as a built-in](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=exclude/3), so you mightn't actually need to define it yourself.

Now, to apply the above predicate to a list of lists:

```
delete_punctuation(_, [], []).
delete_punctuation(Code, [L|Ls], [NewL|NewLs]) :-
  exclude(Code, L, NewL),
  delete_punctuation(Code, Ls, NewLs).
```

However, again, depending on the implementation, a built-in like [`maplist/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=maplist/3) could be used to achieve the same effect without having to define a new predicate:

```
?- maplist(exclude2(33), [[45,33,6],[4,55,33]], X).
X = [[45, 6], [4, 55]] ;
false.
```

n.b. if you want to use all SWI built-ins, `exclude/3` requires the test to be a goal, like so:

```
?- maplist(exclude(==(33)), [[45,33,6],[4,55,33]], X).
X = [[45, 6], [4, 55]] ;
false.
```

For a more general approach, you could even add all the codes you want to exclude (such as any and all punctuation character codes) to a list to use as the filter:

```
excludeAll(_, [], []).
excludeAll(Codes, [Code|Xs], Ys) :-
  member(Code, Codes),
  !,
  excludeAll(Codes, Xs, Ys).
excludeAll(Codes, [X|Xs], [X|Ys]) :-
  excludeAll(Codes, Xs, Ys).
```

Then you can add a list with all the codes to delete:

```
?- maplist(excludeAll([33,63]), [[45,33,6],[4,55,33,63]], X).
X = [[45, 6], [4, 55]] ;
false.
```

Comment: Thank you! With this and with the help all the comments beneath my post I got an answer that was more than I hoped for.